# using cordova (phonegap) plugin within angularJS app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using AngularJS with a Cordova plugin i created which exports an object called deviceAttributes with different methods.
do i have to do anything special in my JS code in order for me to be able to access that object's methods?
what i'm getting from the console is:

**hardwareTypeErr Invalid action AttributesController.js:12
not working AttributesController.js:13**

so it looks like it can't find the method by action for some reason. this works on a simple html5 app without angularjs

here is my code:
Login controller code:

LoginApp.controller('AttributesController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

```
$scope.testAttributesController = function(){
    function hardwareTypeSucc(data)
    {
        console.log("hardwareTypeSucc " + data);
    }
    function hardwareTypeErr(data)
    {
         console.log("hardwareTypeErr " + data.toString());
         console.log("not working");
    }
        var x =deviceAttributes.getHardwareType(hardwareTypeSucc,hardwareTypeErr);
};


}]);
```

cordova plugin plug.js file:

```
var deviceAttributes = {
getHardwareType: function(success, failure){
    cordova.log("getHardwareType");
    cordova.exec(success, failure, "Device", "getHardwareType", []);
},
getOSType: function(success, failure){
    cordova.exec(success, failure, "Device", "getOSType", []);
}

};

module.exports = deviceAttributes;
```

Comment: I would use Ionic, that uses AngularJS: http://ionicframework.com/

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
seems the project already had a plugin with the same name, having both screwed it up.